# Protractor: Access properties of returned Object

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, javascript-objects

I've got the following problem:
My HTML code locks like

```
<div *ngFor="let device of viewModel.devices; let i=index">
    <input type="radio" name="devices" [value]="device" [(ngModel)]="viewModel.selectedDevice">
        My content...
</div>
```

The important part is the "ngModel" which returns an object (in typescript):

```
class Device {
    constructor(public name: string, public kind: DeviceKind) {

}}
```

I would now like to get the properties "name" and "DeviceKind" (which is an enum) which is stored in the ngModel.
I managed to get the "ngModel" content of all devices in the following way (a bit ugly):

```
element.all(by.xpath("//*[@id='deviceList']/div/input")).then(function (items) {
  items.forEach(function (item) {
      item.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model");   // TODO: How to access the returned object properties
});
```

(The id is in a higher div element). This code returns all objects "[object Object]". (If I write console.log(item.getA...), or check the browser DOM)
My problem is: How can I access the returned object properties? Is it possible at all?
I tried something like:

```
item.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model").name
item.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model").then(function(name){...}
```

**Update:**
I tried to make it more simple:
My mage now contains following lines of code:

```
<div id="tempTest">{{selectedDeviceName}}</div>
```

My test contains following code:

```
expect(element(by.id('tempTest')).getText()).toEqual('XXXXXX');  // To test if element really exists
var value = element(by.id('tempTest')).evaluate('selectedDeviceName');
```

The result is: `unknown error: Cannot read property '$eval' of undefined`

I tried a even more simple evaluation (should work, not sure):

```
element(by.id('tempTest')).evaluate('4+3');
```

Afterwards I printed out the request as well as the response:
Request:

```
POST /session/b0eb1b5a-3d96-4350-9029-01377249b251/execute HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"script":"try { return (function (element, expression) {\n  return angular.element(element).scope().$eval(expression);\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }","args":[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"0.34935142695585064-12","ELEMENT":"0.34935142695585064-12"},"4+3"]}
```

Response:

```
{"sessionId":"b0eb1b5a-3d96-4350-9029-01377249b251","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Cannot read property '$eval' of undefined\n  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.125)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)"}}
```

It seems that it tries to get the scope of the element, but fails.

Answer (score 1):

For protractor/selenium `getAttribute()` api,  it can only return string value or null, can't return an object. So you use wrong way in your code.

If you want to obtain the value in `ng-model` of Angularjs, there are two optioins:

**Option 1** use protractor api `element().evaluate()`, only work on Protractor 5.0 and later 
For Detail please look protractor official [API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) document.

**Option 2** inject javascript to browser to get the value, work on any Protracor version

```
var script = 'return angular.element(arguments[0]).scope().$eval(arguments[1]);';
browser.executeScript(script, element(by.xxx(...)).getWebElement(), 'viewModel.devices')
```